# Force window.top.location.href to reload inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, iframe

I have form inside an iframe

```
<iframe name=“name_12341323556” class="wpwl-target" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" style="display: inline; width: 100%; height: 580px;">
#document
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css">
    <title>3D test payment</title>
</head>
<body text="#08297B">

    <form name="acsform" action="https://test.ppipe.net/action” method="POST">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>PASSWORD:</td>
          <td><input id="password" name="password" type="password"></td>
          <input type="hidden" name="vpc_3dset” value="3VrAhRyM4k5s8RGM1fFpwalwCFg=">
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input name="commit" value="Submit" type="submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </form>


</body></html>


</iframe>
```

**UPDATE**

After more digging , found out the reason for redirect is not the submit of the form, the response for the form comes with a redirect logic which forces the page to redirect

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="/v1/paymentWidgets/js/Spinner.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoadDocument()">
           <div id="infoForScriptEnabled" style="display:none">
            <p>You are being redirected in 0 seconds. If this doesn't happen, please <a target="_top" href="http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;ec2-54-171-52-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com&#x2f;api&#x2f;test&#x3f;id&#x3d;A6583FC808A9B2E98FAD5D012EAE343E.sbg-vm-tx02&amp;resourcePath&#x3d;&#x25;2Fv1&#x25;2Fcheckouts&#x25;2FA6583FC808A9B2E98FAD5D012EAE343E.sbg-vm-tx02&#x25;2Fpayment">Click here to continue</a></p>
           </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onLoadDocument() {
                var spinner = new Spinner({}).spin(document.body);
                document.getElementById("infoForScriptEnabled").style.display = "block";
                window.top.location.href = "http\x3A\x2F\x2Fec2\x2D54\x2D171\x2D52\x2D4.eu\x2Dwest\x2D1.compute.amazonaws.com\x2Fapi\x2Ftest\x3Fid\x3DA6583FC808A9B2E98FAD5D012EAE343E.sbg\x2Dvm\x2Dtx02\x26resourcePath\x3D\x252Fv1\x252Fcheckouts\x252FA6583FC808A9B2E98FAD5D012EAE343E.sbg\x2Dvm\x2Dtx02\x252Fpayment";
            }
        </script>

        <noscript>
            <a target="_top" href="http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;ec2-54-171-52-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com&#x2f;api&#x2f;test&#x3f;id&#x3d;A6583FC808A9B2E98FAD5D012EAE343E.sbg-vm-tx02&amp;resourcePath&#x3d;&#x25;2Fv1&#x25;2Fcheckouts&#x25;2FA6583FC808A9B2E98FAD5D012EAE343E.sbg-vm-tx02&#x25;2Fpayment">Click here to continue</a>
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

I cannot modify this response so I need to for the redirect again to be inside my iframe.

With Teemu suggestion I can prevent the page from reloading but this will not do the reload inside the iframe.

Comment: Not sure if it'll actually work, but you could try to sandbox the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), and not allow top navigation ..?

Comment: @Teemu thanks , already tried this but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prevent the native form submission then submit the form using an AJAX POST and listen for the response.

I've faked the request below, but the same should work for your site.

```js
(function(){
  "use strict";
  
  const request = ({ method, action, data }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', resolve);
    xhr.addEventListener('error', reject);
    xhr.open(method, action);
    xhr.send(data);
  });
  
  const fakeRequest = () => request({ method: 'GET', action: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Tiny-Giant/a82536362d0530eebc76bdcfe9e6f122/raw/5df210478c69fab5682ef279728bd96a48933019/response.html' });
  
  const form = document.querySelector('form[name="acsform"]');
  form.addEventListener('submit', async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { method, action } = form;
    const data = new FormData(form);
    // const response = await request({ method, action, data });
    const response = await fakeRequest({ method, action, data });
    console.log(response.target.responseText);
  });
})();
```

```html
<form name="acsform" action="https://test.ppipe.net/action" method="POST">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>PASSWORD:</td>
      <td><input id="password" name="password" type="password"></td>
      <input type="hidden" name="vpc_3dset" value="3VrAhRyM4k5s8RGM1fFpwalwCFg=">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input name="commit" value="Submit" type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```